# Css changes asp tablecell, without resizing it

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I make a tablecell using C# in my code behind, and I add a CSS class to the label inside the cell to rotate it:

```
.vertical {color:#333;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
                -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
                white-space:nowrap;
                display:block;
                }
```

The problem is that after I rotate my label, my table cell (and table) have not resized to fit the new text. Is there a way using CSS or an attribute I can use to have my table re-size automatically to fit the new content?

I'd appreciate any help.

---EDIT---
So after playing around with some the CSS class, I realized the source of my problem. Basically, after I apply CSS changes - my tables don't resize. They still size as if the content was not modified.

Is it possible to make my tables re-size after the CSS style changes the size of my tablecells?

Comment: We're going to need more code.  Show us your html or edit this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/UfeWQ/

Comment: Your fiddle has the vertical class on the whole table. The OP specifies that it is only on the label within a cell.

Comment: Unfortunately the rotated element still occupies space as though it is not rotated.  I think you may need to account for this yourself with padding.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I really wanted the table to resize to fit the new element. @JamesMontagne Thanks for the comment, but my issue is that table both needs to shrink in width, and increase in height (an unknown amount because that content is created dynamically). 

Michael: You know, I may get something to work if I use the rotate css class on the whole table... I'll see how that affects my other table elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the new `height` of your Label and then set it's containing element to that height.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfeWQ/2/) is what I am talking about.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="someLabel" class="vertical">some stuff</td>
        <td>some other stuff sljk fkas jd</td>
    </tr>    
    ...
</table>​
```

and then using jQuery

```
$.fn.textWidth = function () {
    var html_org = $(this).html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html_calc);
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).html(html_org);
    return width;
};

$(function(){
    var someLabelSize = $("#someLabel").textWidth();
    $("#someLabel").css("height", (someLabelSize + 5));    
});
```

Just change the selectors to reflect your needs.